# Group by based on repeating column values of panda df to sum/average other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df looking like this:

```
    Activity    Count   angle_1frame_abs
87  11.2454 4   1.9863239600400613
88  14.3124 4   1.633204419481332
89  7.15621 4   1.7235925045363631
90  1.02232 4   1.4205234792290875
172 6.13389 1   1.9096280055821166
187 1.02232 3   1.7052938965382456
188 7.15621 3   1.708833899378485
189 2.04463 3   1.2728507985832682
233 4.08926 1   1.554572584797844
265 4.08926 2   1.512615236089327
266 5.11157 2   1.4850900583919704
281 6.13389 1   1.162132169753371
305 3.06694 2   2.3605660470439824
306 3.06694 2   1.5685525010916657
385 5.11157 2   1.6579646804948973
386 2.04463 2   2.121520877298791
407 5.11157 4   1.1528498264361269
408 12.2678 4   1.7986876725933032
409 9.20082 4   1.5502484587771188
410 2.04463 4   1.6302871732665316
```

The column "Count" has stretches of repeating values that I would like to use to group the df.

In the above example I would have 8 groups.

I struggle keeping repeating values as separate groups.

My final aim would be to either average (Activity) or sum (angle_1frame_abs) the other columns based on these groups.

My desired output would be something like this (note: the activity and angle_1frames_abs values are made up):

```
Activity Count angle_1_frames_abs
9   4   1.7
6   1   1.9 
4   3   1.7
4   1   1.5
4   2   1.4
6   1   1.1
4   2   1.5
8   4   1.5
```

I have been trying something like this but this only gave me groups based on unique values in the "count" column.

```
df.groupby(["Count"]).angle_1frame_abs.sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create groups using `diff` + `ne` + `cumsum`. The idea is to check if the value appears consecutively and if not, check where it breaks. Then `cumsum` is used to assign distinct numerical value to groups:

```
groups = df['Count'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

From the given input, this creates:

```
87     1
88     1
89     1
90     1
172    2
187    3
188    3
189    3
233    4
265    5
266    5
281    6
305    7
306    7
385    7
386    7
407    8
408    8
409    8
410    8
```

Note that this assigns "Counts" to different groups even if they are the same as long as they are not consecutive.

Then you can use `groupby` on `df` by these new groups. For example, the average of "Activity" for each group is:

```
out = df.groupby(groups)['Activity'].mean()

Count
1    8.434083
2    6.133890
3    3.407720
4    4.089260
5    4.600415
6    6.133890
7    3.322520
8    7.156205
```

Also, in case the original grouping column is not numeric (or a mix of dtypes), an alternative would be to use shift (thanks @StevenS):

```
df['count'].ne(df['count'].shift()).fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define every column you want to keep on your aggregation function:

```py
df.groupby(["Count"]).agg({k: ['sum', 'mean'] for k in df.columns}).reset_index()
```

This here code calculates the sum and average for every column per group, hence this will work only with a dataframe that has only numeric columns.
Here is a version that will work for streches of groups:

```py
# firstly, create a helper column called "groups" (this col will signify
# when a value is changed in the Count column):
df['groups'] = None
group = 0
for i, j in df.iterrows():
    if i == 0:
        df.loc[i, 'groups'] = group
        valueBefore = df.loc[i, 'Count']
        continue
    if j.loc['Count'] != valueBefore:
        group += 1
    df.loc[i, 'groups'] = group
    valueBefore = df.loc[i, 'Count']
# then you can use it to groupby all other columns, i.e.:
df.groupby(["groups"]).agg({k: ['sum', 'mean'] for k in df.columns}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you @Mario, this already gets me a big step closer. The problem is that it groups across all unique values of the column "Count" and hence I end up with only 12 rows as in the example that I show above. I would like to group by each stretch of numbers i.e. 1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1 should be 3 separate groups and not just 2 groups.

Comment: Sorry that it took some time to get back to you @Tahnee, I've updated the solution, check it out and let me know if it works for you now